# Aside div lingers at the bottom of the page instead of the right

Tags: html, css, angular

My goal is to have a form that you can type things in and click add and it goes in a box on the right.

I have created a form in a section and the box in an aside. I have styled them as I think right, but the aside is always below the end of the form. The more on the form, the more the aside goes down. I want it to the right at the top always.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I created a stackblitz that recreates the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wjwsj8.

My styles.css:

```
aside {
  border: 1px solid #6495ED;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

My HTML template:

```
<h3>Toppings</h3>
<section>
  <label>Pizza Topping
    <input [(ngModel)]="currentTopping" placeholder="Pizza Topping">
  </label>
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="onAddClick()">Add</button>
  <p class="error">{{message}}&nbsp;</p>
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="onApplyClick()">Apply</button>
</section>

<aside>
  <p *ngFor="let aTopping of settingsService.toppings">{{aTopping}}</p>
  <p *ngFor="let aTopping of settingsService.newToppings" class="ghostText">{{aTopping}}</p>
</aside>
```

Comment: section {float: left;}

Comment: You've made close to no efforts researching. Or, if you researched it, you forgot to mention it. You might argue you read the definition of `float` but it looks like you did not have a look at simple usage examples. Please have a look at the accepted answer of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Given it's highly unlikely to help anyone else, I suggest its deletion.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I have researched. I went to several sites, including reading all of the information on www.w3schools.com. I could not figure out how to put together a decent search for "my one div keeps ending up under another div." I asked a couple of colleagues, but they didn't have much more experience than me, so I posted here. Why is it unlikely to help someone else? If someone had already posted an answer to this question, I wouldn't have.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks to @Ylama. I added

```
section {float: left;}
```

to my styles and that fixed the problem. I knew it had to be something simple, but I couldn't figure it out.